# SVN: How to switch from remote repository to local?

Tags: svn, repository

I have an SVN repository on a remote server. My local working copy accesses it through the svn:// protocol. I want to move the repository to my local PC. I've copied the repository over, but when I try to switch (relocate) my working copy to use the local repository (accessing it just through the file system - no server running), svn complains that it's not a valid relocation.

I.e. the Windows command 'svn switch --relocate svn://diskstation/svnrepository c:\Users\Bob\Documents\svnrepository' gives the error 'svn: E200004: 'svn://diskstation/svnrepository' to 'C:/Users/Bob/Documents/svnrepository' is not a valid relocation'

How can I get my working copy to start using the local repository?

Thank you,
   Bob

Comment: BTW, switch `--relocate` deprecated a lot of versions ago. You **must** to use `svn relocate` in up-to-date SVN-client. And running svnserve local will be better solution technicaly

Answer (score -1):

To specify a file path, use file:/// e.g. file:///C:/Users/Bob/Documents/svnrepository

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. Perhaps explaining how this answers the specific question posed by OP will make it more clear how this answers the question.

Comment: Instead of using 'C:/Users/Bob/Documents/svnrepository' in the switch command, use 'file:///C:/Users/Bob/Documents/svnrepository'.

Comment: Bob, please read the help section to learn how Superuser works. This information should be added to your answer rather than be placed in a comment. It should not be necessary to read the comments to learn the answr